# UIImage to NSData fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I use `NSData` to convert `UIImage` from photolibrary to `NSData` but it gives.

> error fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
>   value

Following is my code

```
if(o.count == 1)
{//o is [UIImage]
    let imgdata:NSData? = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.o[0], 10)
    print(o[0]) //it show <UIImage: 0x14e123cb0>, {30, 40}
    print(imgdata)
}
```

Comment: If print shows a UIImage (not nil) then the error is somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

if o.count == 0, the array is empty. So you are trying to create NSData from an empty array here

```
UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.o[0], 10)
```

It's safer to do

```
if let imgdata = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.o[0], 10) {
   ...
}
```

So your app doesn't crash if it returns nil. Swift knows that UIImageJPEGRepresentation returns NSData, so you don't need the `:NSData?` in the if statement.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks I'll edited in if `o.count`  case but I want to convert UIImage to NSData to upload to server with alamofire frameworks

Comment: Yeah in `if (o.count == 1)` I use `let imgdata = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.o[0], 10)` and print it still error

Comment: You are supposed to pass a value between 0.0 and 1.0.

Comment: @Leo I tested that out, but it doesn't seem to be the issue. Apple's code will probably just round it to 1

Comment: Try dropping the self.

Comment: That's what I was wondering, if there's another o out of the scope of what we can see

Comment: @YasuhiroKondo you should show a little bit more of your code otherwise we would be just guessing. BTW you should choose better (more descriptive name for your vars

Comment: I'll take horizontal image it not error but I use vertical image in error

Comment: @YasuhiroKondo if count == 1 You are not forcing unwrapping anything there. make sure all your IBOutlets are properly connected and there is no extra connection that you forgot to delete after changing any outlet

Comment: I'll upload in github wait

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3r_c-kIc9vUVjhiQ3IwLXlaOUE&usp=sharing This is my code I have problems with Github Sorry for wait  too long time

Comment: I cannot download the file. Google is unable to zip the file. Can you re-upload it to google drive or dropbox pre-zipped?